# Combine two obserable booleans with either ObservableBoolean or Observable<Boolean>

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, rx-java, observable

In JavaFX you can do the following to combine two observable booleans:

```
BooleanProperty imagesDownloaded = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);
BooleanProperty animationComplete = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);

BooleanBinding isValid = imagesDownloaded.and(animationComplete);
```

How can I do the same with either RxJava or the Databinding API of google?
I also want to listen to value changes on the `isValid` variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Observable.combineLatest()`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/combinelatest.html), [`Observable.zip()`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html), [`Observable.merge()`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/merge.html), and other [operators](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators.html) depending on your goals.

I'll just add a short example to show what this could look like in RxJava:

```java
PublishSubject<Boolean> property1 = PublishSubject.create();
PublishSubject<Boolean> property2 = PublishSubject.create();

Observable.combineLatest(property1,
                         property2,
                         (propertyOneValue, propertyTwoValue) -> propertyOneValue && propertyTwoValue)
          .subscribe(isValid -> doWork(isValid));

// sometime later
property1.onNext(true);
property2.onNext(true);
```